# Add relation to Neo4j with Neo4j.Driver

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher

I am a C# developer new to Neo4j. I have spent a couple of weeks learning the graph concept and trying out Cypher. It is so far a good experience!

I now tried to work with some real data from code through the official C# driver. I was surprised to find that the driver is merely a wrapper of the APIs with no real .Net functionality on top.

When creating nodes I managed fine to create Cypher statements with this pattern:

```
CREATE (:Movie {tmdbId: {tmdbId}, imdbId: {imdbId}, title: {title}, originalTitle: {originalTitle}, collectionInfo: {collectionInfo}, genres: {genres}, releaseDate: {releaseDate}, plot: {plot}, tagline: {tagline}, originalLanguage: {originalLanguage}, tmdbPopularity: {tmdbPopularity}, tmdbVoteAverage: {tmdbVoteAverage}, tmdbVoteCount: {tmdbVoteCount}, budget: {budget}} )
```

Parameter collection is automatically generated from object. It works fine. But when creating relations I get an unexpected error.

This is the statement I use to create relations. Source and target nodes are looked up by Id.

```
MATCH (s:Person), (t:Movie) WHERE s.personId=35742 AND t.movieId=19404 CREATE (s)-[r:ACTED_IN {order: {order}, character: {character}}]->(t) RETURN r
```

The error I receive is:

```
System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: 'Parameter count mismatch.'
```

The parameter collection is created the same way as last time. It holds two properties named "order" and "character" as expected.

Is there some error in the statement that I am missing?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Add object as node in Neo4j database.
    /// All public properties will automatically be added as properties of the node.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">Generic POCO object</param>
    /// <param name="label">Specify type name to be uses. Skip if you are satisfied with object type name.</param>
    public void AddNode(object obj, string label = null)
    {
        using (var session = _driver.Session())
        {
            label = label ?? obj.GetType().Name;
            var parameters = GetProperties(obj);
            var valuePairs = string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => $"{p.Key}: {{{p.Key}}}"));
            var statement = $"CREATE (:{label} {{{valuePairs}}} )";
            var result = session.Run(statement, parameters);
            Debug.WriteLine($"{result.Summary.Counters.NodesCreated} {label} node created with {result.Summary.Counters.PropertiesSet} properties");
        }
    }

    public void AddRelation(string sourceNodeName, string sourceIdName, string targetNodeName, string targetIdName, string relationName, object relation, string relationSourceIdName, string relationPropertyIdName)
    {
        using (var session = _driver.Session())
        {
            //MATCH(s:Person), (t:Person)
            //WHERE s.name = 'Source Node' AND t.name = 'Target Node'
            //CREATE(s) -[r:RELTYPE]->(t)
            //RETURN r           
            var parameters = GetProperties(relation);
            var sourceId = parameters[relationSourceIdName];
            var targetId = parameters[relationPropertyIdName];
            var properties = parameters.Where(p => p.Key != relationSourceIdName && p.Key != relationPropertyIdName).ToList();
            var valuePairs = string.Join(", ", properties.Select(p => $"{p.Key}: {{{p.Key}}}"));
            var statement = $"MATCH (s:{sourceNodeName}), (t:{targetNodeName}) WHERE s.{sourceIdName}={sourceId} AND t.{targetIdName}={targetId} CREATE (s)-[r:{relationName} {{{valuePairs}}}]->(t) RETURN r";

            var result = session.Run(statement, properties);
            Debug.WriteLine($"{result.Summary.Counters.RelationshipsCreated} {relationName} relations created with {result.Summary.Counters.PropertiesSet} properties");
        }
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, object> GetProperties(object obj)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var propertyName = property.Name;
            var value = property.GetValue(obj);

            var array = value as string[];
            if (array != null)
            {
                value = string.Join(",", array);
            }
            if (value is DateTime)
            {
                var dateTime = (DateTime)value;
                value = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            }

            dictionary.Add(propertyName.ToCamelCase(), value);
        }
        return dictionary;
    }
```

Comment: Hello Jakob! I copied, pasted and ran your query in my Neo4j browser and worked fine! So I think that your question is related to your C# code, right? Can you share the C# code that generates the query with us? Also, are you using the [Neo4jClient library](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient)?

Comment: Thanks @BrunoPeres for fast response!! You are right, the statement works fine in Neo4j browser, so I guess it is related to C# wrapper. I added my methods above for your review. I suspect the problem is related to curly braces inside square bracket making it hard for the Run method to parse the statement and the parameters?

Comment: What is the output of `Debug.WriteLine(statement);`?

Comment: I can of course make a workaround where the complete statement is generated with inline date, but I really would like to avoid that. I guess there is a reason for the parameter approach to avoid "Cypher injection attacks" :)

Comment: To clarify: your exception occurs in the `AddRelation` function, right? So, can you put a `Debug.WriteLine(statement);` between `var statement = $"MATCH (...)` and `var result = session.Run(...)`?

Comment: MATCH (s:Person), (t:Movie) WHERE s.tmdbId=35742 AND t.tmdbId=19404 CREATE (s)-[r:ACTED_IN {order: {order}, character: {character}}]->(t) RETURN r       The properties collection holds two valid items with key names: order and character.

Comment: I seems to me that the problem is related to the `valuePairs` variable generation...

Answer (score 0):

Bruno set me in the right direction! It was not a problem with neither Cypher nor the wrapper. My mistake was to filter the parameters collection and return a property list instead of keeping it as a dictionary.

The adjusted working method now looks like this:

```
    public void AddRelation(string fromNodeName, string fromIdName, string toNodeName, string toIdName, string relationName, object relation, string relationFromIdName, string relationToIdName)
    {
        using (var session = _driver.Session())
        {
            //MATCH(s:Person), (t:Person)
            //WHERE s.name = 'Source Node' AND t.name = 'Target Node'
            //CREATE(s) -[r:RELATIONTYPE]->(t)
            //RETURN r           
            var parameters = GetProperties(relation);
            var fromIdValue = parameters[relationFromIdName];
            var toIdValue = parameters[relationToIdName];
            var properties = parameters.Where(p => p.Key != relationFromIdName && p.Key != relationToIdName).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
            var valuePairs = string.Join(", ", properties.Select(p => $"{p.Key}: {{{p.Key}}}"));
            var statement = $"MATCH (s:{fromNodeName}), (t:{toNodeName}) WHERE s.{fromIdName}={fromIdValue} AND t.{toIdName}={toIdValue} CREATE (s)-[r:{relationName} {{{valuePairs}}}]->(t) RETURN r";
            var result = session.Run(statement, properties);
            Console.WriteLine($"{result.Summary.Counters.RelationshipsCreated} {relationName} relations created with {result.Summary.Counters.PropertiesSet} properties");
        }
    }
```